Question About RabbitMQ Batch Publishing And Ordering Messages
I have a list of messages need to be sent to rabbitMq. I am using masstransit and i publish messages one by one like this;
foreach (var @event in events)
{
   await _bus.Publish(@event, ....); 
}

But with this approach throughput is very low, so i want to try batch publishing somethig like this;
 var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var @event in events)
{
   var  t = _bus.Publish(@event, ....); 
   tasks.Add(t);
}
await Task.WnenAll(tasks);

//and with this configuration;
hostConfigurator.ConfigureBatchPublish(x =>
  {
   x.SizeLimit = 256 * 1024;
   x.Enabled = true;
   x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4);
   x.MessageLimit = 100;
  });

My question is: With this batch publishing method, will the order of the messages being sent to RabbitMQ still be preserved same as first one by one method?
I tried publish messages one by one but throughput is very low.

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

They should be delivered to the broker in-order, yes. You can also use the PublishBatch extension method instead of looping yourself.
